# Crud app - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am following CRUD tuts and I am trying to delate classes in table. But I got stuck...

Classes.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Classes")
public class Classes {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "class_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String classId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "max_numb_students")
    private int max_numb_students;

    @Column(name = "min_numb_students")
    private int min_numb_students;

    public String getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }
    public void setClassId(String classId) {
        this.classId = classId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getMax_numb_students() {
        return max_numb_students;
    }
    public void setMax_numb_students(int max_numb_students) {
        this.max_numb_students = max_numb_students;
    }
    public int getMin_numb_students() {
        return min_numb_students;
    }
    public void setMin_numb_students(int min_numb_students) {
        this.min_numb_students = min_numb_students;
    }

    public Classes() {

    }

    public Classes(String classId, String name, String description, int max_numb_students, int min_numb_students) {
        super();
        this.classId = classId;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.max_numb_students = max_numb_students;
        this.min_numb_students = min_numb_students;
    }

}
```

Controller.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/classesTable")
public class ClassesController {
    @Autowired 
    private ClassesRepository classesRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listClasses(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("classes", classesRepository.findAll());
        return "classesTable";
    }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/{classId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable String classId) {
          System.out.println(classId);
          classesRepository.delete(classId);
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/classesTable");
        }
}
```

ClassesRepository.java

```
public interface ClassesRepository extends CrudRepository<Classes,String>{

}
```

And I am getting this error

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No class com.oggi.model.Classes entity with id {classId} exists!

Comment: does a class with your given id exist in database?

Comment: @Janar yes it exists

Comment: suppose you have to use a unique id with the Classes. use `Long` id as the `@id`.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I did that and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I create a project like this and works ok using String id, the only one difference is that I use JpaRepository instead of CrudRepo.  Using long id is a better solution but in case that you need the String id it also works.

domain: DataCenters.java

```
@Entity
public class DataCenters {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String location;

    public DataCenters() {
    }

    public DataCenters(String name, String location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataCenters{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", location='" + location + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Repo: DataCentersRepository

```
public interface DataCentersRepository extends JpaRepository<DataCenters,String> {
}
```

controller: DataCentersController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/datacenters")
public class DataCentersController {

    private final DataCentersRepository dataCentersRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DataCentersController(DataCentersRepository dataCentersRepository){
        this.dataCentersRepository=dataCentersRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listClasses(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("datacenters", dataCentersRepository.findAll());
        return "datacenters";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        dataCentersRepository.delete(id);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/datacenters");
    }


}
```

Boot Application: MyJpademoApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyjpademoApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyjpademoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyjpademoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner(ServerRepository serverRepository, DataCentersRepository dataCentersRepository){
        return (args) -> {

            logger.info("Creating Data Centers...");
            dataCentersRepository.save(new DataCenters("StarFox","nowhere"));
            dataCentersRepository.save(new DataCenters("Axelay","nowhere"));
            dataCentersRepository.save(new DataCenters("NinjaGaiden","nowhere"));
            dataCentersRepository.findAll().stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        };}}
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:h2:mem:~/test
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.boot.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>myjpademo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myjpademo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer mate! :)